# Linux Mint : logitech keyboard : change highlight color key

Tags: drivers

I have a gamer logitech keyboard : G810 and  would like to change the color of the illuminated keys.

So I want to install gnome15 but why is it so painfull ? Could you help with PPA, apt-get or I do not know what else... I have seen this but I always have diferent errors reparing...https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gnome15 AND https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_modifier_sources_maj#recharger_la_liste_des_paquets

So, if you a a good alternative, or a simple solution, such as apt-get install AND NOT autoconf, make... or I do not what else...please feel free to help.

Thanks you

Answer (score 3):

I have a G810 myself, and I'm using Linux Mint 18, though not with drivers for the keyboard.

However, it is possible to change the colors using the keys on the keyboard itself.

Dim-key + 0 sets a fixed color and cycles through available colors,
Dim-key + 1 sets wave pattern
etc.

It looks like keys 1 through 5 and 0 are the keys that allow you to set different patterns if you hold the Dim-key pressed.
Just play around with them a bit until you get a setting you like.

If you feel like giving this a try [G810 driver for Linux](https://github.com/MatMoul/g810-led). I have not tried it msyelf, I just want one solid color, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in controlling the leds on you keyboard, I have a project on github [LogiGSK](https://github.com/MohamadSaada/LogiGSK) and your keyboard is one of the supported types and the software is very easy to install, there is a GUI to control the leds and there is a Linux daemon to keep the profile you choose on startup or after resume from suspend or hibernate. Please note that not all keyboard layouts are available (currently US only for G810, G610, G410 and both US and UK for all G910 models). If your layout is not included and you want it to be added just open an issue and I'll add it as soon as possible.